# How to show different navigation bar for each page using angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, navbar, angular6

I have 4 different navigation bar in my application.

I need to use different navigation bar for different pages. I need to show a navigation bar for login, then for dashboard & then for other logins & its screens.

My tabs-header.html file:

```
  <div class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/category" class="nav-link">CATEGORIES</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">REPORTS</a>
</div>

<div  class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/category" class="nav-link">REGISTERATION</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">CO REGISTERATION</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">COO</a>
</div>

<div class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/category" class="nav-link">MCC</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">MSP</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">MEE</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">MC</a>
</div>

<div class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/category" class="nav-link">REGISTERATION</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">CUSTOMER REGISTERATION</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">ERT</a>
</div>
```

My header-tab-component ts file:

```
 export class TabsHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  visible: boolean; 
  cookieValue = 'NEW';
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService,
  public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   let a = this.cookieService.get('navbar');
   console.log("this.cookieValue"+this.cookieValue);

    }

  }
```

My login ts file:

```
 _initialize(): void {
     this.cookieService.set( 'navbar', 'login' );
  }
```

Can i store some values in cookie & use that value in some if condition in my tabs-header.html?

Like this,

```
<div *ngIf= {{ a }} class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/category" class="nav-link">CATEGORIES</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">REPORTS</a>
</div>
```

or shall I use like

```
<div *ngIf = "router.url = '/login'">
 <a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/category" class="nav-link">CATEGORIES</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">REPORTS</a>
```

Can somebody suggest me how to do this please?